# send user id to analytics through google tag manager

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, gtag.js

I am attempting to send the user id through google tag manager to google analytics.

I have a field to set in my gtm trigger that sets the variable `userId` to the value of `{{userId}}`.

I then attempt to set it in my javascript in the following way `window.dataLayer.push({'userId': parseInt(account.id)});`.

Upon using the analytics debugger in chrome I can see that the user id is not being applied to events reported afterwards.
[image: analytics debugger]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before GTM snippet in `HEAD`:

```
dataLayer.push({'userId': parseInt(account.id)});
```

Comment: I have [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/d-v/d31f05a95410eb2b75a182ce7e0bb957) in HEAD, I also have also included it in the main gtm snippet too [like this](https://gist.github.com/d-v/d31f05a95410eb2b75a182ce7e0bb957)

Comment: I also tried setting default value of userId to something like -1 in the gtm console, even that still shows null on reported events :(

Comment: gtag chrome debugger sees the message but gtm apparently doesn't do anything about it

Comment: Have you the same problem using dataLayer.push...?

Comment: Yes I do, both methods yield the same result

Comment: Did you create in GTM a data layer variable named 'userId' and set it as value of 'useId' field in 'Field to set' inside the Google Analytics tag settings? https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/4565987?hl=en